# Email issues to a specific email provider (bellsouth.net) failing with "stat=Data format error"

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

I have a site that sends emails to users. One user in particular is not receiving emails. I have looked at the logs and I found:

```
Nov  9 21:27:22 ******** sendmail[28960]: 0A9LRK37028960: to=**********@bellsouth.net, ctladdr=********** (1000/4), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=31941, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (0A9LRKwX028961 Message accepted for delivery)

Nov  9 21:27:22 ******** sm-mta[28963]: 0A9LRKwX028961: to=**********@bellsouth.net, ctladdr=******************** (1000/4), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=122066, relay=*************. [***********], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
```

There are hundreds of other emails to other email addresses that are working fine.

How do I get more information about "Data Format Error", or what things could I change to see if it resolves the error? Is it possible that the issue is with bellsouth.net?

The email is being sent via a PHP script using phpmailer. It is a multipart text/html with an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested debug procedure for deliveries to `example.net` :

1. Use mailertable entry below to select dsmtp mailer for deliveries to `example.net`:

   ```
   examle.net  dsmtp:%0
   ```

It will put message to `example.net` in queue without delivery attempt

2. As root push queened messages for `example.net` in verbose mode (with smtp session transcript).  Execute the command below in terminal:

   ```
   sendmail -v -qRexample.net
   ```

Comment: Thanks - turns out we got on to AT&T's blacklist. Googling for how to get removed paints a grim picture and the automatic removal request tool seems to longer be around :(